# What can be expressed in and proved with the internal logic of a topos?

Tags: ct.category-theory, lo.logic, topos-theory, categorical-logic

The title of this post expresses what I really want, which is to learn how to wield the internal logic of a topos more effectively. However, to bring it down to earth, I'll ask a few basic questions about the topos $\mathcal{Grph}$ of directed graphs, whose underlying category is 
$$\mathcal{Grph}:={\bf Set}^{\mathcal{G}}.$$ 
Here $\mathcal{G}$ is the indexing category for graphs, with two objects $A$ and $V$ and with two morphisms $src,tgt\colon A\to V\ $.

What can I express in the internal logic of the topos $\mathcal{Grph}$, say using the Mitchell-Benabou language or the Joyal-Kripke semantics, or what have you? How can I use this logic to prove things? What kinds of things can't be said or proven in this way?

Below are some concrete questions. In each case when I ask "Can I...", I mean "To what degree can I use the internal language and logic of $\mathcal{Grph}$ to...".

1. Can I express that a graph $X$ is finite, (respectively complete, discrete)?
2. Can I take a graph $X$ and produce the
   paths-graph $Paths(X)\ $, whose
   vertices are those of $X$ but whose
   arrows are all finite-length paths
   in $X$?
3. Can I express that $Paths$ is a monad, i.e. produce some morphism $X\to Paths(X)\ $ and another $Paths(Paths(X))\to Paths(X)\ $ with some properties?
4. Can I take a graph $X$ and produce the subgraph $L\subseteq X$ consisting of all vertices and arrows that are involved in a loop? (That is, an arrow $a\in X(A)$ is in $L$ iff there exists a path $P$ of length $n$ in $X$ such that $a\in P$ and $P$ is a loop: $P(0)=P(n)\ $. A vertex $v\in X(V)$ is in $L$ if it is the source of an arrow in $L$.)
5. Can I prove that if a graph has no loops and finitely many vertices then it has finitely many paths?
6. Can I do something else in $\mathcal{Grph}$ that might be fun and informative?

Maybe this post reflects a basic misunderstanding of how to think about the internal logic of a topos. If so, please set me straight. Also, a quiz question might be nice -- something of the form "see if you can express/prove this in $\mathcal{Grph}$: ***_*_**."

Comment: I suspect the answer to all your questions, other than the one about finiteness, is no. In the internal logic of a topos, objects are "sets" and have no further internal structure. That is not to say we can't tack on extra gadgets to make that internal structure visible – for example, we could introduce some local operators to extract the edge set and the vertex set – but then you may as well work from the external point of view.

Comment: David, it is really hard for me to make your question precise. The reason is that in an internal logic of any category we talk about *internal* things. For example, there is no internal formula "X is a finite graph" true for all finite (in any sense) graphs, because "X" have to be bounded to the internal structure of an object in the category. (cont)

Comment: On the other hand, for a given graph G, a formula "X is a finite graph" (i.e. X is a subgraph of G and is finite) may be easily constructed by taking the large disjunction over all finite (in any sense) subgraphs of G (in cocomplete toposes, algebras of subobjects have arbitrary disjunctions).

Comment: The idea of using an internal logic is not to reason in a particular category, but to perform a uniform reasoning for all categories satisfying some properties --- in exactly the same way as there is no sense to use the logic of a particular Heyting algebra to reason about that Heyting algebra.

Comment: Actually, [Kuratowski-finiteness](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/finite+object) can be formulated within geometric logic, and a Kuratowski-finite object in $\textbf{Grph}$ is precisely a graph $G$ with finitely many edges and finitely many vertices, such that the two maps $G(A) \to G(V)$ are surjective. In fact, the finite graphs are precisely the Kuratowski-_subfinite_ objects.

Comment: @Zhen Lin: true, the internal logic talks about all objects as though they were just unstructured sets.  But one can still often re-express external local notions in these terms — see e.g. the internal construction of a sheafification.  Talking about local operators, for instance, isn’t tacking on anything extra: they can be described entirely using the internal logic itself, as constructions based on certain elements of $\mathcal{P}(\Omega)$.  (From the internal point of view, they’re just Grothendieck topologies on the terminal category.)

Comment: @Michal: *one* idea is to use the internal language of a class of categories to prove their general properties. *Another* idea is to use the internal language of a *particular* category to prove its properties. @Zhen Lin: you suspect wrong, the game here is *precisely* to figure out what *extras* should be added to the general internal language of toposes. The question never said anything about using just "pure" internal language of toposes.

Comment: @Andrej, I really like your answer --- and not only :-) because it (together with your conversation with Francois) supports what I have said in the above comments. First, you have externally characterised an object $V$ and added its „external” properties as a kind of axioms to the internal logic of a topos. This roughly corresponds to using the internal logic of category Grph. (cont)

Comment: However, both you and Francois felt that such a logic is not really convenient (i.e. showing anything in such a logic is essentially the same as showing that things externally), so you tried to characterise $V$ in the internal logic of any topos and arrived at the axiom “there is a truth value $v \in \Omega$ such that $(v \rightarrow p)=\neg\neg p$ for all $p \in \Omega$”. (cont)

Comment: But now you are not reasoning in the internal logic of Grph, but in the internal logic of all (or any) elementary toposes satisfying your axiom (of course, such logic is pretty useless until you can show any non-trivial interesting facts about objects satisfying your definitions). If I understand correctly the idea underlying the first Francois's question “Why is it important for $V$ to be parameter-free definable?”, it was exactly about “Why it is important for $V$ to be characterisable in the internal logic of a topos?” (cont)

Comment: And if I understand correctly your answer, it was: "Because it is difficult to incorporate external properties of an object with internal reasoning in a topos in a smooth way.".

Answer (score 32, accepted):

In general the internal language of a topos can only express those statements that make sense in every topos. In essence, this limits you to something like bounded Zermelo set theory, without global membership.

The right way to use the internal language of a *particular* topos, such as your topos of directed graphs, is to *enrich* the general internal language of toposes with new primitive types and new axioms. If you are lucky you may be able to add just axiom and define the new types (i.e., the new types can be characterized in the internal language). Let us see what these may be in the case of the topos of directed graphs.

Because we are dealing with a presheaf topos we can tell in advance that the (covariant) Yoneda embedding $y : \mathcal{G} \to \mathbf{Set}^\mathcal{G}$ will give us something important. Indeed, $y(V)$ is the graph with one vertex and no arrows, while $y(A)$ is the graph with two vertices and one arrow in between. Let me write $V$ and $A$ instead of $y(V)$ and $y(A)$, respectively. We might call $V$ "the vertex" and $A$ "the arrow". We call the objects of our topos "graphs", obviously.

Simple calculations reveal that, for a given graph $G$:

- $G \times V$ is the associated discrete graph on the vertices of $G$.
- $G^V$ is the associated complete graph on the vertices of $G$.
- $G \times A$ is the following graph: for each vertex $g$ in $G$ we get two vertices $(g,s)$ and $(g,y)$ in $G \times A$ (think of them as "$g$ as a source" and "$g$ as a target"), and for each arrow $a : g \to g'$ in $G$ we get an arrow $a : (g,s) \to (g',t)$ in $G \times A$. This probably means something to graph theorists, I would not be surprised if they have a name for it.
- $G^A$ is the associated "graph of arrows": the vertices of $G^A$ are pairs of vertices $(g,g')$ of $G$; and for each arrow $a : g \to h$ we get an arrow $a : (g,g') \to (h',h)$ in $G^A$. This makes more sense once you compute the global points of $G^A$: they correspond precisely to the arrows in $G$. Also, it is helpful to think of the vertices of $G^A$ as "potential arrows of $G$".

We can already answer some of your questions:

- A graph $G$ is discrete when the projection $G \times V \to G$ is onto.
- A graph $G$ is complete when the canonical map $G \to G^V$ is onto.

You would like to have the graph of paths $\mathsf{Path}(G)$ of a given graph $G$. I think you've described the wrong gadget, i.e., what you should be looking for is a graph whose *global points* are the paths in $G$, but there will be many other "potential" things floating around. We have so far not used the fact that there are two morphisms $s, t : A \to V$. These allow us to form "generic paths of length $n$" $P_n$ as pullbacks: $P_1 = A$, $P_2 = A \times_V A$ is the pullback of $s : A \to V$ and $t : A \to V$, and so on. With a little bit of care we should be able to form the object of "generic paths" $P$, equipped with a concatenation operation that turns it into a monoid. I am going to naively guess that the vertices of $P$ are pairs of natural numbers $(k,n)$ with $k < n$ and that arrows are of the form $(k,n) \to (k+1,n)$. But this needs to be checked, and in any case it should be possible to define the "correct" $P$ internally. The graph $\mathsf{Path}(G)$ that you are looking for  ought to be the dependent sum $\sum_{p : P} G^p$ (and this looks a lot like a polynomial functor). The monoid structure on $P$ should give you a monad.

Regarding cyclic paths (you call them loops): if I am not mistaken the internally projective graphs are those graphs whose in- and out-degrees are all 1, in other words the cycles and the infinite path stretching in both directions. This should help with getting a grip on cyclic paths. That a graph $G$ is internally projective can be expressed in the internal language as "every $G$-indexed family of inhabited graphs has a choice function", i.e., these are the objects that satisfy the axiom of choice, internally.

The vertex $V$ is a subobject of the terminal object $1$, which is the graph with a single vertex and a single arrow. Thus, there is a corresponding truth value $v \in \Omega$, which is a kind of "intermediate" truth value. We can define a closure operator $j : \Omega \to \Omega$ (a modality) by $j(p) = (v \Rightarrow p)$. This modallity should be called "vertex-wise". Indeed, if $H \hookrightarrow G$ is a subgraph of $G$ then its $j$-closure $\bar{H} \hookrightarrow G$ is the subgraph of $G$ induced by the vertices of $H$. Ah, but this is then the same as the compleement of the complement of $H$, so we see that $j$ is just the double negation closure. (I hope I am doing this right, I am speaking off the top of my head.)
If I am correct, then we can define $V$ in the internal language, using an axiom:

> **Axiom:** there is a truth value $v \in \Omega$ such that $(v \Rightarrow p) = \lnot\lnot p$ for all $p \in \Omega$.

Then $V = \lbrace * \in 1 \mid v \rbrace$. We still have to do something about $A$, though.

In any case, my experience with internal languages is that they are well worth using. It takes a bit of effort, thoough, to figure out the optimal way of setting up the internal language of a particular topos. The general idea is to introduce as few new types as possible, characterize them with suitably chosen axioms, and figure out what other useful axioms are valid in your topos.

Comment: Why is it important for $V$ to be parameter-free definable?

Comment: That was too brief a question... I didn't read the parameter-free requirement in the op's question. I do find it interesting when something is parameter-free definable and I'm happy you are addressing that issue, but I wonder why you find it such a sticking point.

Comment: I am not sure I understand you. What would be a parameter-non-free definition of an object?

Comment: "A graph $G$ is discrete when the projection $G\times V \to G$ is onto" defines discreteness using $V$ as a parameter. Later, you show that there is a parameter-free definition since $V$ is definable (up to isomorphism). Am I missing the point of the last few paragraphs where you argue that $V$ is definable?

Comment: I do not think of $V$ as a parameter. It is a primitive type in the internal language of the topos of graphs, i.e., it is a *constant*. It is no more a parameter than the type $N$ of the natural numbers. It is good that we can characterise $V$ up to isomorphism wiht an internal statement, because then its interpretation is fixed.

Comment: OK, I understand. Since it's conservative to add such a constant there is no harm done, but why is it advantageous to add $V$ as a constant rather than use it as a parameter? (Sorry for bugging you with all these questions, I'm just very curious to understand your point of view.)

Comment: I do not understand this parameter business. The internal language of the topos of graphs is a type theory. Every object of the topos is a type, i.e., the internal language is a real mix of semantics and syntax. Also, there is no such thing as a "parameter type". We might do some things *schematically* by using metavariables in place of types. So perhaps this is different from set theory, where sets are individuals that can be parametrized over in the language. In the topos language, anything of the form "for all types, ..." is not part of the language.

Comment: OK. I'm lost now. Are we talking about the same thing? At what point do you need quantification over all types? Let's back up... What is "the projection $G\times V \to G$ is onto"? (I interpret it as the usual way of saying that the projection $G \times V \to G$ is epi in the internal logic.)

Comment: So, the discrete graphs (as identified by peeking into the objects) are precisely the graphs such that $G \times V \to G$ is epi. There is a simple formula in the internal logic, which evaluates to $\top \in \Omega$ precisely for such $G$.

Comment: But $V$ is a specific graph here. Why is it important that $V$ is definable in the internal logic? Isn't it sufficient that $V$ exists?

Comment: Ah, I see. You're distinguishing the fact that $G$ is not a variable in the internal logic. I think I'm on the same page now. Still, that doesn't explain why you want $V$ to be definable.

Comment: If I just have some type $V$ and know nothing about it, that is not very useful. I need to know some properties, so I can start proving things.

Comment: OK. I see, and you want to prove these in the internal logic. There are many ways to look at this and I now see I was blindsided. Thanks for your patience, Andrej.

Comment: Oh, I am actually grateful to you for drilling into this. I thought it was obvious we wanted to do things internally, so we needed some internal axioms to start from. It's sometimes very hard to guess what the audience is really thinking :-)

Answer (score -4):

A beautiful question; thank you!

First, you can as well take Set and see if its boolean two-valued logic helps in any way to tell a finite set (definitions vary) from an infinite (definitions vary). It does not.

In Grph the subobject classifier is pretty simple, it consists of two vertices (T and F) and five arrows (two trivial ones, one from T to F, one from F to T, and one from T to F, impersonating those arrows that originate and end in a subgraph, but do not belong to it).

What can you do with it? Hardly anything. There are exactly four Grothendick topologies in this topos, and that's it.

Comment: I’m not sure I follow your second paragraph.  The logic of **Set** certainly can tell the difference between a finite and an infinite set.  Of course, it doesn’t do so in a novel way, since the logic of **Set** is just (a large fragment of) the logic we reason in all the time.  But that novelty is exactly what can get more interesting when one moves to a different topos!

Comment: @PeterLeFanuLumsdaine can you give more details on how logic can help distinguish a finite set from an infinite set? I don't see how.

Comment: Many of the usual definitions of finite can be written in the internal logic of a topos. For instance, the formula “there is some n in Nat such that there is some bijection between X and {1,…,n}” will hold (in the internal language of Set) exactly if X is finite in the usual sense.

Comment: @PeterLeFanuLumsdaine `Nat` is not necessarily present in a topos. Of course the idea about an isomorphism between a [0..n] and an X does define finiteness. But I don't see how logic is involved here. We don't even need a subobject classifier for that.

Comment: sorry, yes, I usually work with toposes with an NNO, and forget not everyone assumes that.  In the absence of an NNO, you can still define an equivalent sense of finiteness, but the definition is slightly more complex: $X$ is finite precisely if it satisfies “$X$ is Kuratowski-finite [i.e. any subobject of $PX$ containing singletons and closed under binary joins must contain the maximal subobject], and any two elements of $X$ are either equal or not equal” in the internal logic.

Comment: Peter, this definition sounds new to me; I liked it a lot; thank you!